# Change For loop to Recursion

Tags: java, data-structures

I was asked to Write a recursive method that takes as a parameter a nonnegative integer and generates the following pattern of stars. 
    If the nonnegative integer is 4, then the pattern generated is:

```
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
```

Also, write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of lines in the pattern and uses the recursive method to generate the pattern. 
For example, specifying 4 as the number of lines generates the above pattern.
 */

My code: However, recursion is not working any ideas? or suggestions?

```
    public static void printStars(int lines) {
        if (lines==1) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print("*");
            printStars(lines-1);
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this exercise it to help you learn what recursion is for.  The way to print the N star case is:

1. print N stars
2. print the N-1 star case
3. print N stars again

The reason you recurse in step (2) is because that's how you can go off and do something else (printing the N-1 star case) without messing up the stuff you have to remember to continue when that is done (N).

That makes the recursive implementation easier to understand than the interative one:

```
public static void printStars(int N) {
    if (N<1) {
        return;
    } else if (N==1) {
        printLine(N);
    } else {
        printLine(N);
        printStars(N-1);
        printLine(N);
    }
}
private static void printLine(int len) {
    for (;len>0;--len)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

When the solution to the problem includes a smaller version of the same problem, *that's* where you recurse.

The iterative solution is not so bad, but it requires you think about the problem differently:

1. Print the upper triangle
2. Do the reverse to print the lower triangle, taking care to omit the first line

Like this:

```
public static void printStars(int N) {
    for (int i=N; i>=1; --i)
        printLine(i);
    for (int i=2; i<=N; ++i)
        printLine(i);
}

private static void printLine(int len) {
    for (;len>0;--len)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

In a lot of ways this is a better solution.  It's faster and it consumes less stack space.  But it requires you to have a kind of global insight into what the shape of the whole solution looks like.  When you read it, it's a lot harder to figure out what it does.

A lot of problems are made much easier to understand by breaking them into smaller versions of the same problem, and that is why recursion is used so often in algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You understand the need for a base case, which is great. Your base case is nearly correct. It currently outputs a single star, but it needs to output a single star and then end the line.

Your recursive case needs more work. The recursive call you make is correct. However, before you make the recursive call, you need to output `lines` stars and then end the line. After you make the recursive call, you need to do that again. If you are not allowed to use a loop at all, you may have to make a second recursive function to output the correct number of stars.